# How to replace the navigator object on the popup in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

How can I replace the navigator object on the popup?

I can replace the navigator by using `page.initialized` callback, but it has no effect for popups.

In the PhantomJS, I can use something like this:

```
page.onPageCreated = function (newPage) {
  newPage.onInitialized = function () {
    newPage.evaluate(function() {
      window.navigator = {/*some code*/}
    });
  }
};
```

How to do it on CasperJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CasperJS is built on top of PhantomJS. Provided it works in PhantomJS, then it will also work in CasperJS.

1. You can either directly access `casper.page` to run the same code as in PhantomJS or
2. You can use the [`popup.created`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#id2) event handler to do the same in CasperJS:

   ```
   casper.on("popup.created", function (newPage) {
     newPage.onInitialized = function () {
       newPage.evaluate(function() {
         window.navigator = {/*some code*/}
       });
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: You are right. I've looked into the code, turns out `page.created` is a plain CasperJS event and has nothing to do with PhantomJS' `onPageCreated`.